Learning path of Algebraic Geometry and differential geometry for students in numerical PDE
I am a student in the direction of numerical PDE, in the past few years, algebraic geometry and differential geometry and conformal geometry has been used in structured grid generation, see papers like "Quadrilateral and hexahedral mesh generation based on surface foliation theory", and I think in our computer any nonlinear system is discretized as polynomials systems with rational number coefficients, and hence can be transformed to polynomials system with integer coefficients, and there are some paper about using real algebraic geometry method to find the initial value for Newton-iteration to approximate the global minimal(sorry I forget which paper it is), so these factors let me want to learn more about differential geometry and algebraic geometry, my major in bachelor is Math, and know a some about Abstract algebra, and some part of differntial geometry, but my knowledge of differential geometry doesn't contain advanced topics like connections or something more advanced, could you please recommend some learning path? thank you
